# Spring Security, Problem with PasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

i have a problem with PasswordEncoder,

my code:

```java
@Service
public class UserService {

    private static final String DEFAULT_ROLE = "ROLE_USER";
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private UserRoleRepository roleRepository;
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Autowired
    public UserService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder){
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository){
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserRoleRepository(UserRoleRepository roleRepository){
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    public void addWithDefaultRole(User user){
        UserRole defaultRole = roleRepository.findByRole(DEFAULT_ROLE);
        user.getRoles().add(defaultRole);
        String passwordHash = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(passwordHash);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

}
```

error:

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in org.spring.service.UserService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' in your configuration.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way ( One of two bean, not both):

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfigAuthentication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        //   For BCrypt Encoded password

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
           PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
           return encoder;
        }


         OR


        //   For no Encoder, plain text password

        @Bean
        public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
           return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For dependency injection to work, you need to acually declare a bean of the appropriate type, otherwise there is nothing to be injected. Exactly that is telling you the exception.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); // or any other password encoder
}
```

Comment: I add your code to UserService, but i have another problem

Comment: Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  userService defined in file [C:\Users\...\UserService.class]
└─────┘



Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Put the bean to a separate `@Component`. Right now, you want to inject a `PasswordEncoder` in your `UserService`, but that is excatly the component who declares it.